# archlinux - How to get the package stats(usage counts) from command line?

Tags: awk, arch-linux

Is there any command line interface to the [archlinux package usage statistics](https://pkgstats.archlinux.de/package)? I looked ant `pkgstats` and couldn't find any such option.

I would like to have something like this:

```
$ statpkg kitty
1392: kitty
95: kitty-git
74: kitty-framework
8: kittypack-git
```

Answer (score 1):

When you visit the page you linked to, you open the network tab of your browser (press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> and go to network tab) and then refresh. One of the requests gives back a JSON response. Right click on that and copy that url and you can use it to download the data.

You could then define a manual function using `curl` and `awk` as follows:

```
statpkg(){ 
    curl -s "https://pkgstats.archlinux.de/package/datatables?draw=4&columns%5B0%5D%5Bdata%5D=pkgname&columns%5B0%5D%5Bname%5D=&columns%5B0%5D%5Bsearchable%5D=true&columns%5B0%5D%5Borderable%5D=false&columns%5B0%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bvalue%5D=&columns%5B0%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bregex%5D=false&columns%5B1%5D%5Bdata%5D=count&columns%5B1%5D%5Bname%5D=&columns%5B1%5D%5Bsearchable%5D=false&columns%5B1%5D%5Borderable%5D=true&columns%5B1%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bvalue%5D=&columns%5B1%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bregex%5D=false&order%5B0%5D%5Bcolumn%5D=1&order%5B0%5D%5Bdir%5D=desc&start=0&length=25&search%5Bvalue%5D=$1&search%5Bregex%5D=false&_=1559313142337" | 
    awk 'BEGIN{RS="[{}]";FS="[\":]"} {if ($9) print $9": "$5}' 
}
```

example usage:

```
$ statpkg awesome
2452: ttf-font-awesome
1913: awesome-terminal-fonts
1835: awesome
1347: otf-font-awesome
652: ttf-font-awesome-4
649: python-qtawesome
409: python2-qtawesome
368: otf-font-awesome-4
302: fontawesome.sty
101: plasma5-applet-awesome-widgets
75: awesome-terminal-fonts-git
65: awesome-themes-git
60: awesome-freedesktop-git
57: awesome-terminal-fonts-patched
54: awesome-git
48: otf-font-awesome-5-free
43: awesome-revelation-git
34: awesome-luajit-git
28: awesomebump
25: python-qtawesome-git
24: awesome-gnome
21: awesome-scratch-git
18: otf-fontawesome
15: awesome-cinnamon
15: blackarch-config-awesome
```